# What is right in this situation, "I want to walk" or "I want to take a walk"?

Tags: meaning, idiomatic-language

When I woke up in the morning at my house.
and I want to get some fresh air. So I walk to my school near my house.
In this case, What is the right expression?

1. I want to walk to my school to get some fresh air.
2. I want to take a walk to my school to get some fresh air.

Answer (score 1):

Native English speaker from the Northeast United States here!

I would be more likely to say the second one above, because "take a walk" means that the goal is the act of walking. If I only say "walk to [place]" it usually means that the goal is to be at the place.

"I want to walk to my school" means "I am going to school (probably so I can go to class), and I will get there by walking (rather than bus, train, or car)."  Then you add the second part of the sentence: "to get some fresh air" and I am confused. Why would you need to be at school to get fresh air? School is inside, right? So when you're there, you aren't getting  fresh air.

But if I read "I want to take a walk to my school" then the focus is on the action of walking, and the path you are walking happens to pass by the school. Then the second part makes more sense.

**Another Thing**

In this example, you say "my school" which means "the school I am a student or teacher at." I wasn't sure if that's what you meant? If you mean to say "the community school that is near my house" you would just say "the school" or "the nearby school".